# change labels orientation,programmatically

Tags: iphone

can we change the orientation of label,programmatically.

i created few labels on landscape mode, but my application works on portrait,
so wen i start my app, the labels still comes according to landscape mode only,

i cant change the orientation of labels through,IB,i hv some restrictions.

so,only option left is, doing it programmatically...and i dont knw how to do it.

quick help is always appreciated

regards
shishir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rotate the desired labels by applying view.transform = CGAfineTransformMakeRotation(degrees * 180 / M_PI());.

You can even do this in an animation block, if you want it animated.
[UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
  view.transform = CGAfineTransformMakeRotation(degrees * 180 / M_PI());
}];